# interpreting cpuinfo

Tags: intel, xeon, central-processing-unit

I have to figure out what kind of cpu my HS20 have. Its /proc/cpuinfo output is below. Is that mean It has two IntelXeon units with two cores each ?

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
stepping        : 1
cpu MHz         : 3600.260
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
runqueue        : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm lm
bogomips        : 7182.74

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
stepping        : 1
cpu MHz         : 3600.260
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
runqueue        : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm lm
bogomips        : 7182.74

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
stepping        : 1
cpu MHz         : 3600.260
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 6
siblings        : 2
runqueue        : 2
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm lm
bogomips        : 7182.74

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 15
model           : 4
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 3.60GHz
stepping        : 1
cpu MHz         : 3600.260
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 6
siblings        : 2
runqueue        : 2
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm lm
bogomips        : 7182.74
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have 2 dual core processors which is the [maximum configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?subtype=ca&infotype=an&appname=iSource&supplier=897&letternum=ENUS105-019) for a HS20.

Answer (score 0):

You have two physical processors:

```
physical id     : 0
physical id     : 6
```

Each with two threads:

```
runqueue        : 0
siblings        : 2
...
runqueue        : 2
siblings        : 2
```

Comment: In that case, this is probably [this](http://ark.intel.com/products/27088/64-bit-Intel-Xeon-Processor-3_60-GHz-1M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB) cpu. What about `# of Threads` specified there. I see 1 thread, not two.

Comment: I'm not certain about Hyper Threading, but I'm sure that those are two cpus that either have two cores or have HT. Dual cores are shown as `cpu cores       : 2` and `core id         : 0`, `core id         : 1` with `siblings        : 2` on my single Core 2 Duo (with Linux 3.0) and Pentium4 has `core id         : 0` for both threads and `cpu cores       : 1` on Linux 2.6.26.

Comment: You could try running `dmidecode`, its possible it will provide more detailed information.

Comment: Oh, and the Pentium IV has `siblings        : 2`